# Audio isn't working in JS

Tags: javascript, audio

I am making a game that features multiple audio clips. When I ran the game locally, it worked fine, but when I hosted it on a server 2 audio clips stopped working. I am using these audio clips just like all the others, and I even tried shortening the audio clips, but nothing worked. These are the main background music to my game, so it is pretty important.

On one HTML and JS page, I have the following code.

```
function music(){
var snd = new Audio('Sure.mp3');
snd.volume = 0.5;
snd.play();
}
music();
setInterval(music, 115000);
```

And it doesn't work, even though it works locally.

```
var backgroundDeathMusic = new Audio('gameOver.mp3');
var backgroundMusic = new Audio('Metal.mp3');
function music(){
    if(songTimer==933000){
        songTimer = 0;
    }
    if(songTimer==0){
        backgroundMusic.volume = 0.5;
        backgroundMusic.play();
    }
    songTimer++;
}
function deathMusic(){
    if(deathMusicTimer==933000){
        deathMusicTimer = 0;
    }
    if(deathMusicTimer==0){
        backgroundDeathMusic.volume = 1;
        backgroundDeathMusic.play();
    }
    deathMusicTimer++;
}
function musicDecider(){
    if(lifeCounter>0){
        music();
        backgroundDeathMusic.pause();
    }
    if(lifeCounter<=0){
        deathMusic();
        backgroundMusic.pause();
    }
}
```

And on this one only the backgroundDeathMusic/gameOver.mp3 one works, despite it having the same code. Can someone tell me why, please.

Thankyou so much.

Comment: is the file there?

Comment: Maybe it isn’t buffered yet. I encounter this problem if a sound file isn’t buffered and after trying to play it again three or four times it finally plays…

Comment: I am pretty sure the file is there, i asked the person managing the server to check to make sure he got the file.

Comment: Also I tried playing it a few times, still nothing

Comment: That should work as long as the mp3s are in the same folder as the page that contains your code.  You can check if they're there by browsing to `http://your.server.com/path/to/your/page/Metal.mp3` - if you get 404 it's not there.